# Have there been any instances where both of a state's Senate seats flipped to the opposing party in a single election?

Tags: united-states, election, senate, history

The Democratic candidates flipped both of Georgia's Senate seats, previously held by Republicans, in the 2021 runoff elections.

Such a situation where both Senate seats of a state change party in *a single election* should be rather uncommon since:

1. both Senate seats have to be up in a single election (meaning that at least one has to be a special election)
2. both Senate seats have to flip

So, has this happened before? If so, how many times?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, this has happened five times<sup>1</sup>.

I modified this list of ["double-barrel"<sup>2</sup> Senate elections](https://centerforpolitics.org/crystalball/articles/the-minnesota-twins-a-complete-history-of-double-barrel-senate-elections/), published by the UVA Center for Politics, to show only the elections where both Senate seats of a state flipped to the opposing party in a single election.

> [image]

---

<sup>1</sup>Includes only elections after 1913 when the [Seventeenth Amendment](https://www.senate.gov/artandhistory/history/common/generic/SeventeenthAmendment.htm), which established the direct elections of Senators, was passed.

<sup>2</sup>Occurs when "both a Senate special election and a regularly-scheduled Senate election [are] held on the same day in the same state". ([source](https://www.centerforpolitics.org/crystalball/articles/south-carolina-doubles-down-on-2014/))